# Android - Running tasks in the background in order of request

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service

It's my first time here. I hope I'm clear enough with my question.

I want to have a `Decoder` object initialized at the start of an Activity and stays idle until it is request to do `Decoder.decode(int x)`, which I want to run in the background and in the order of request.

For example, `Decoder.decode(int x)` takes more than 1 second to finish but I call request it to run once every second. I want a call to `Decoder.decode(int x)` waits for the previous call to finish before it starts executing.

Currently, I'm using `Service` and bind it to my activity. The initialization part is done in `onBind()`. Every time a request is made, the service creates an AsyncTask and run `Decoder.decode(int x)` inside its `doInBackground` method. Is that the right approach or should I do something else?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should always use AsyncTask for time consuming operations

Comment: @RajPatel Yes, I'm using AsyncTask right now but I dont' know how to make the a request waits for the one before it to finish before starting to run.

Comment: see `HandlerThread` class, read [this](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/handlerthreads-and-why-you-should-be-using-them-in-your-android-apps-dc8bf1540341#.78reeomk6), section `How do I use HandlerThreads` or [this](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/efficient-android-threading/9781449364120/ch08.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a blocking queue of AsyncTasks or threads to perform operations in order. You can also use a library such as this:

https://github.com/path/android-priority-jobqueue